# Routine work-out suggestions

Tags: workout-routines, post-workout, pre-workout

I used to go the gym since I was 16 then I stopped at 19 because of university (I used to do both martial arts and body building). Now I started again, and it's been one about 8 months since I re-started, I only focus only on body building. So basically i'm try to develop both mass growth and definition (I mean... I'm aware that there's to be some tradeoff between two of them).

I go to the gym at alternate days (like monday-wednesday-friday-sunday-tuesday-thursday-saturday... and i start over).

Broadly in the first day I do both chest and biceps, in the second day triceps and back, third day legs and shoulder, and then I start over.

I've noticed some changes in my body, so I think my work out so far is good, however in the last period i'm noticing that i'm a little stucked with the weight. It's a matter of resistence, as example if with the curl barbell I lift up to 15 kg (I mean performing correctly the exercise up to that weight)  then if I try (as example) to lift 17 kg I still don't have the resistance to complete the exercise, with "resistance" I mean that if with the 15 kg i'm able to close correctly my arm (bringing the bar bell almost to touch my chest) when i try to put some weight more i can't close entirely my arm (but i'm still able to do all the repetitions, but not correctly).

Same as some other exercises (not all of them). In case like this is there some kind of support/auxiliary exercise that could be useful to perform? Or some specific training style one could follow? Could be somehow related to the diet too? (maybe a healthier diet, like more protein I don't know... just guess).

I'm just asking for general suggestion and reference. I could give you more details of my work out if you think they could be useful.

Comment: Stagnation is normal. You obviously can't have linear progression forever. What matters is how you deal with it.

Comment: And how could i deal with it? is there a kind of "correct way"? but understand that the "correct" depends on the person.

Comment: I turned the comment into an answer, since it was a bit longer than 500 characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stagnation is normal. You obviously can't have linear progression forever. What matters is how you deal with it.

**Variety**

Usually, we deal with it by employing variety. If you've done the same program for 8 months, it's time to switch to something new. The body derives strength from progressive overloading, and that is hard to achieve if you just to the same thing over and over. Kind of like how you won't get better at math by solving 2+2 for 8 months.

**Deload**

It can often be useful to deload for a week or two first. This means simply giving your body a "vacation". It doesn't mean you shouldn't train altogether, but you just take it easy for a while, and let your body fully recuperate and rejuvenate.

**Schedule**

As far as your schedule goes, every-other-day is just fine. There's no reason to stop doing that, unless you find a program that specifically advises *n* times per week.

**Diet**

When trying to lift heavier, it's usually the norm to also gain bodyweight, both muscle and fat. Gaining strength without gaining weight is one of those things that is very difficult to do, and usually not worth the hassle unless you compete.

Some basic foods that WILL assist your progress are the usual high-carb, high-protein meals. You should make sure that most meals include the three basic ingredients;

- a protein
- a starch
- some vegetables

For protein, meats and fish are the goto. Pretty much just pick one. Tuna, chicken or turkey are pretty popular in the fitness scene.

For starch (which is the carb source), I'm a huge fan of brown rice, potatoes, or sweet-potatoes.

Vegetables are also pretty straight-forward. Even frozen vegetables are good, and easy to prepare. Broccoli, cauliflower, spinach, carrots... You get the point.

Comment: I don't get the point of the schedule. What you mean? It is not necessary to follow my routine? (one day yes, one day not... etc?)

Comment: Like I said, your schedule is just fine. But some training programs are meant to be done let's say 3 times a week.

Comment: Could i have any benefit if i would work out more often in a week?

Comment: Yeah, absolutely. But you have to pay attention to what your body tells you. Some people can easily work out 6 days a week, and still regenerate enough in between. Others need to limit themselves to 3 days a week, just to make sure they get enough restitution. In either case, you need to eat and rest accordingly.

Comment: A silly question... general suggestion on what to eat? some reference maybe would help?

Comment: Added a diet section to the answer.

Comment: Ok thank you, maybe for further more specific question it's worth to create a new question.

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: I like your comment, you just forgot some techniques like negative reps, small pauses between some reps, piramidal loading (from high weigth to low weight)...

Comment: All those are good points @Krotanix. If possible, you should add an answer that builds on mine and adds those techniques.

Comment: I just said that so you could update yours, if you wanted :)